# Regular expression for Apache redirection

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

In the .htaccess file I would like to redirect (301):

From: `http://www.example.com/photo<anything>`
To: `http://www.example.com/blog/`

Basically, any URL starting with `/photo` should be redirected to the single URL `/blog/`. What is the regular expression for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found out:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/photo/ http://www.example.com/blog/`

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your server is apache with mod_rewrite enabled:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^photo(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

and if upper or lower case characters are acceptable, then use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^photo(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Because of the redirect, I'd recommend using the full absolute URL to redirect to instead of a relative URL because an rfc document (I forgot the rfc number) once stated that the Location header on a redirect page must be a full absolute URL but then another rfc document later stated the URL can be relative, but if you want to increase compatibility for every web browser, I'd suggest using absolute URLs for all redirects.

Comment: I do use mod_rewrite. This solution seems similar to the one I've posted above. I guess yours would not limit to photo/ but to anything photo like photography/ for instance.

Comment: thats correct. You did state "Basically, any URL starting with /photo should be redirected to the single URL /blog/" Which means "/photo" and "/photograph" and "/photography".

Comment: One of both should be set as valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regular expression.   The `Redirect` directive handles that case easily:

```
redirect permanent /photo/ http://www.example.net/blog/
redirect permanent /photo http://www.example.net/blog
```

in the *.htaccess* file for the `example.com` server.  By default, the redirect directive saves anything additional on the path (`/photos/hello`) and appends it to the destination (`/blog/hello`).

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I want to redirect anything starting with /photo to /blog/ . I don't want to append to /blog

Comment: `/photo` to `/blog` or `/photo` to `/blog/`...

Comment: /photo to /blog/ (my urls have a traling slash, if that's the question)

Comment: `my urls have a traling slash` so you mean `/photo/` to `/blog/`?

Comment: I usually use a pair of redirects for that.   One for without the slash, and one with the slash

Comment: That does not work. It redirects http://www.example.com/photo/anything to http://www.example.com/blog/anything   Like I said, anything starting with /photo should be redirected to the exact url http://www.example.com/blog/